# Does assembly code ignore const keyword?

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-construction, constants

Does assembly code when used(linked) in a c project ignore **const** keyword declared before C datatypes and functions?? And can it modify the contents of the datatypes??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does assembly code when used(linked) in a c project ignore const
>   keyword declared before C datatypes and functions??

Yes, the `const` keyword is utterly ignored by assembly code.

> And can it modify the contents of the datatypes??

If the compiler was able to place a `const` location in a read-only segment, then assembly code trying to modify it will cause a segmentation fault. Otherwise, unpredictable behavior will result, because the compiler may have optimized parts of the code, but not others, under the assumption that `const` locations were not modified.

Answer (score 3):

> And can it modify the contents of the datatypes??

Maybe, maybe not.  If the original object was declared `const` then the compiler might emit it into a read-only data segment, which would be loaded into a read-only memory page at runtime.  Writing to that page, even from assembly, would trigger a runtime exception (access violation or segmentation fault).

You won't receive a compile-time error, but at runtime your program might crash or behave erratically.

Answer (score 1):

Assembly uses the datatypes you declared in C to better optimize how it stores the information in memory.  Everything is written in binary at the end of the day (int, long, char, etc), so there is no datatypes once you get to the low level code.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not very precise. What does "ignores" mean?

Assembly language does not have the same concept of `const` as C language does. So, assembly cannot ignore it. It simply has no idea about it.

Yet the assembly code generated by C compiler for a C program might easily be affected by the placement of `const` keywords in your C program.

In other words, assembly code can be *affected* by `const` keywords. But once that assembly code is built, the `const` keyword is no longer necessary.

To say that assembler can modify something declared as `const` is not exactly correct either. If you declare a variable as `const`, in some cases the compiler might be smart enough to eliminate that variable entirely, replacing it with immediate value of that variable. This means that that `const` variable might disappear from the final code entirely, leaving nothing for the assembly code to "modify".

Comment: Ok, I will elaborate the situation. I have a .asm file linked to my c project and i pass const parameters to the functions in .asm file from my c source file and the contents of the const datatype i passed are being changed.

Answer (score 0):

GCC places global variables marked as const in a separate section, called .rodata. 
The .rodata is also used for storing string constants.

Since contents of .rodata section will not be modified, 
they can be placed in Flash. The linker script has to modified to accomodate this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
const int a = 10 ;
int main ( void ) {
  return a ;
}

    .section .rodata
    .align 4
a:
    .long   10
```

gcc with 00 :

```
    movl    a(%rip), %eax   // variabile constant
    addq    $32, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
```

gcc with O3 :

```
    movl    $10, %eax       // numeric constant
    addq    $40, %rsp
    ret
```